# Nestjs: empty body when post multipart/form-data with DTO and whitelist = true

Tags: typescript, post, file-upload, nestjs, multipartform-data

I create an `POST` with `multipart/form-data`.

```
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
@Post('upload')
@ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
uploadFile(@Body() body: FileDto, @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
  console.log('body: ', body)

  return 'uploaded'
}
```

FileDto:

```
export class FileDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  name: string

  @ApiProperty({ type: 'string', format: 'binary' })
  file: any
}
```

**The `console.log`**

When `whitelist: true`: `body:  {}`.

When `whitelist: false`: `body:  { name: 'some name' }`

Swagger:
[image]

And `pipe` validation with `class-validator` seem not work with `multipart/form-data`

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `whitelist: true`, class-validator strips unknown values from the payload. As your `FileDto` has no `class-validator` decorators, the `name` is properly stripped. Either add `@Allow()` or a class-valdiator validation decorator to keep the property.